# How to iterate over Stripe subscription collection

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I'm currently integrating with Stripe and before I update an existing the Subscription I need to retrieve all existing subscriptions to find the correct Subscription Id.

However, when I use the Stripe PHP library I seem to be unable to iterate over the actual subscription collection.

This is how I retrieve the subscription collection:

```
$subscriptions = $customer->subscriptions->all();
```

I have also tried this, which should be the same and doesn't seem to make difference in the end result:

```
$subscriptions = \Stripe\Customer::retrieve( $customer->id )->subscriptions->all();
```

For sanity sake, after obtaining the subscription collection I `echo` a `count()` on it to see how many elements it contains:

```
echo count( $subscriptions );  // echos '1' which is what I expect.
```

When I `print_r()` the entire `$subscriptions` object I do indeed see the one existing subscription, so I have verified that it has been retrieved.

I then want to simply iterate over the collection with a `foreach`. This should be possible because the `StripeObject` (a base class for the returned collection) implements `ArrayAccess`:

```
foreach( $subscriptions as $subscription )
{
   print_r( $subscription );
}
```

However, this doesn't result in anything.

How do I correctly iterate over a Stripe subscription collection?

Comment: $subscriptions is a StripeList object, $subscriptions->data is the actual array

Comment: No it's not. It's a `Collection` -> `ApiResource` -> `StripeObject` which implements `ArrayAccess`. Other than that, `data` is `protected`.

Comment: test iterating through $subscriptions->data when you print_r it'll appear as protected but it is still accessible.

Comment: Hmm. That seems to work. Very confusing. They really need examples in their API docs rather than just listing those JSON dumps. Thanks for lending me your brain. If you add it as an answer I'll except it as correct.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Stripe "list" API calls return "list objects" or "collections". These objets contain an actual list in their [`data`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/php#pagination-data) attribute.

In PHP, you can iterate over a collection like this:

```
$subscriptions = $customer->subscriptions->all();

echo count($subscriptions->data); // Number of resources returned

foreach ($subscriptions->data as $subscription) {
    // Do something with $subscription
}
```

Comment: Thanks for hanging out here. Do you think it would be possible to have examples of this being reflected in the Stripe reference docs? It currently only shows very basic interaction (i.e. retrieve information) but it doesn't really show how to work with data once retrieved. The JSON blob shown for each method is nice but in the end it doesn't add much value if you're working with one of the libraries where pretty much everything is abstracted.